# Swift: issue when appending items to an array

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm new to swift and am having an issue appending items to an array in a for loop. The very last item appended becomes all the items of the array.I've included the relevant code and the debug area from xcode that shows the output from my print statements. I'm probably overlooking something simple but am really struggling with this one. Can anyone please help?

```
var songArray = []
for item in randomItems! {
    song.title = item.persistentID
    print(song.title)
    songArray.append(song)
    print(songArray.count)
}
print(randomItems!.count)
print(songArray.count)
print(songArray[0].title)
print(songArray[1].title)
print(songArray[5648].title)
print(songArray.last!.title)
```

Debug output:

```
5648665669236166639
5646
5648665669236166139
5647
5648665669236164363
5648
5648665669236164735
5649
5648665669236164702
5650
5648665669236165512
5651
5651
5651
5648665669236165512
5648665669236165512
5648665669236165512
5648665669236165512
```

Comment: Most probably, `song` is an instance of a *class* and you are modifying and appending the *same instance* repeatedly.

Comment: That's probably it, create a new instance inside the loop or make a copy of the object before appending

Comment: It is a class... switched to a struct solved the issue. Thank you!